# How to refer to a range object to pick up RGB value from cells

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to pick up RGB values from cells in the sheet, and format the cell background of another range (multiple areas) to that colour - and as a bonus, format the text to white if the colour is dark.

There's multiple sets of values, affecting different areas. A number of cells have menus to select a colour, and eventually I'd like any change there to automatically trigger formatting of the relevant cells.

I'm trying to pick a set of colours to use in technical reports from the list we're allowed to use by corporate communications. There's a grid where we can see all the combinations side-side and figure out if we can differentiate them - both the fully sighted, and those of us with colour deficiencies.

Ultimately the plan will be to either call one of several outer routines to set the ranges, or pass a variable to use in a case statement.

This works:

```vb
DestColor = RGB(Range("d4"), Range("e4"), Range("f4"))
Sheets("Main").Range("$B$5:$P$5,$B$4,$I$2,$I$4,$I$6,$I$8,$I$10,$I$12,$I$14,$I$16,$I$18").Interior.Color = DestColor
```

This gives

> 1004:Application-defined or object-defined error

```vb
Set DestCells = Sheets("Main").Range("$B$5:$P$5,$B$4,$I$2,$I$4,$I$6,$I$8,$I$10,$I$12,$I$14,$I$16,$I$18")
DestColor = RGB(Range("d4"), Range("e4"), Range("f4"))
Sheets("Main").Range(DestCells).Interior.Color = DestColour
```

I created an object called `DestCells` of type Range, so I should be able to use that anywhere I'd use `Range(...)`.
Is it that I've misunderstood something, or am I getting something wrong in the syntax?

Ultimately I'll be looking to have a sub like this:

```vb
Sub SetCells(DestCells As Range, ColorVals As Range)
  
  vRed = ColorVals.Columns(1)
  vGreen = ColorVals.Columns(2)
  vBlue = ColorVals.Columns(3)
' some more stuff to go in here ...
End Sub
```

But trying to call it like (and simplifying the range for testing):

```vb
SetCells(Sheets("Main").Range("$B$5:$P$5"), Sheets("Main").Range("d4:f4"))
```

gives

> Compile error: expected =

I tried with and without parentheses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this part:

```
Set DestCells = Sheets("Main").Range("$B$5:$P$5,$B$4,$I$2,$I$4,$I$6,$I$8,$I$10,$I$12,$I$14,$I$16,$I$18")
DestColor = RGB(Range("d4"), Range("e4"), Range("f4"))
Sheets("Main").Range(DestCells).Interior.Color = DestColour
```

This line `Sheets("Main").Range(DestCells).Interior.Color = DestColour`
`DestCells` is already a range so remove the `.Range()` And you already referenced the sheet so you don't need `Sheets("Main")`

making:

```
Set DestCells = Sheets("Main").Range("$B$5:$P$5,$B$4,$I$2,$I$4,$I$6,$I$8,$I$10,$I$12,$I$14,$I$16,$I$18")
DestColor = RGB(Range("d4"), Range("e4"), Range("f4"))
DestCells.Interior.Color = DestColour
```

For this part:

```
SetCells(Sheets("Main").Range("B5:P5"), Sheets("Main").Range("d4:f4"))
```

`()` on calls makes it think you are returning something, you want:

```
SetCells Sheets("Main").Range("B5:P5"), Sheets("Main").Range("d4:f4")
```

Comment: Well I now have something that runs, time to flesh it out a bit now. I'm assuming I have this wrong as well "vRed = ColorVals.Columns(1)" as vRed is staying as empty in the locals window ?

Comment: `vRed = ColorVals.Cells(1).Value`.

Comment: OK, it was a bit more fundamental than that - somehow the formulas in those cells had got deleted and I hadn't noticed. With those back in, both ColorVals.Columns(1) and ColorVals.Cells(1).Value. I'll use the latter which looks clearer to me.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sheets("Main").Range(DestCells).Interior.Color = DestColour
```

should be

```
DestCells.Interior.Color = DestColour
```

---

**A couple of other notes:**

1. Once you have set a range you can just refer to it directly like above
2. You can remove all of the locked cell references (`$`). They are not doing your code any favors while decreasing readability
3. You are using both spellings of color (not an issue, just interesting)

Comment: Where's the facepalm icon when you need it. The colour/color thing is a bit of a pita for me - for me, the correct spelling is colour so it's awkward working with a system using color. And now I spot the error that stopped the cells updating. The cell references were copied from the macro recorder, I'll get rid of the $, you're right that they obscure readability.

Comment: ‍♂️ - @Simon56

Answer (score 0):

You could deal with the font colour challenge by reading the cell interior fill ColorIndex (rather than Color) and comparing it against the list of dark ColorIndexes. Here's a function and some code to test... just select an area with different cell colours before running the test sub:

```
Option Explicit
Sub fontColourTest()
    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In Selection
        cell.Font.Color = fontColour(cell.Interior.ColorIndex)
    Next cell
End Sub
Private Function fontColour(interiorColour As Integer)
    Dim darkIndexes As Variant
    Dim i As Integer
    darkIndexes = Array(1, 3, 5, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 16, 18, 21, 23, 25, 26, 29, 30, 31, 32, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56)
    For i = 0 To UBound(darkIndexes)
        If interiorColour = darkIndexes(i) Then
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
    If i > UBound(darkIndexes) Then
        'the interior colour was not found in the dark indexes - use black font:
        fontColour = 0
    Else
        'dark interior - use white font:
        fontColour = 16777215
    End If
End Function
```

There may be a more sophisticated method. This works well if black and white are the goals, but it would be handy to deduce the "opposite" colour directly. Perhaps some simple maths on the RGB values....

Comment: Thanks. That's probably way more than I need - does that approach work for arbitrary RGB values, or just for "standard" colours ? I was just going to do an approximate grey level and then a simple "if grey > somevalue then use black else use white". It should be good enough for this application.

Answer (score 0):

Below a procedure to get the RGB details on a cell.

```
Sub GetRGBDetails()

Dim ColorToGet, NewColor As Double
 
'Get the color of a cell
ColorToGet = Range("A1").Interior.Color
 
'Get the decomposition of color
Red = ColorToGet And 255
Green = ColorToGet \ 256 And 255
Blue = ColorToGet \ 256 ^ 2 And 255
 
'Set the color on a new variable
NewColor = RGB(Red, Green, Blue)

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes it's a useful bit of code, but I'm not looking to get the colour values already set - I have those from a table and just need to set them in a range of cells.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all - a most friendly & helpful group.
All contributions were of use, but that from @Warcupine was the key to understanding where I'd gone wrong. The whole thing is built now - I found it fairly easy once I'd got past that roadblock.
Thanks again.